# inter-http request communication

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-rest, completable-future

The idea was that there are 2 different http requests to 2 different end points. The first one is a long expensive calculation and it returns. The second request goes and does the exact same expensive calculation but before it returns does some extra processing with more data reads and calculations. Instead of doing the exact same calculation twice, it would be nice for the first call to write it's results to a channel or queue and the second http endpoint could join that message with the other data reads and processing before returning.

MessageEndpoints and Service activators can subscribe to a channel but how it would be in the same thread as the second http call on the second endpoint I cannot figure out. To me the mystery is how does the second thread on the second end point block until it receives a message that the first end point creates and sends.

Maybe setting up a polling channel would be the better route to go like on the second end point, it could immediately start polling while doing it's other reads and calculations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a task for an `Aggregator` EI pattern:

http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator

Both requests should correlate to the same group.

I somehow believe that it doesn't matter for your who will return first: only the concern is to perform some post-processing when all the data is gathered.

However I even think that Scatter-Gather is a good choice for you as well:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather

There is a Thread Barrier implementation also for your consideration: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#barrier